# $_REQUEST (or) $_GET functions in php

Tags: php, undefined-index

i am install xampp recently

i will write a function in  php

```
$value=$_GET['value'];
```

but it shows an error "Undefined index"

i will also try $_REQUEST function

plse help me

Comment: What's the URL, do you have `?value=something` in there?

Comment: maybe because `value` does not exist?

Answer (score 5):

It shows undefined index because you did not set the GET parameter `value`. If you will not always be setting it, do something like this:

```
$value = (isset($_GET['value'])) ? $_GET['value'] : 'default_value';
```

...or...

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
  $value = $_GET['value'];
}
```

Essentially, you need to verify that a variable is set before you try and use it or it will generate warnings.

Comment: `ss`? I understand naming is arbitrary, but this OP might well take that literally (as in, a requirement).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment The question originally used `$_GET['ss']` but obviously the OP has edited. Since he realised this distinction, hopefully that won't be an issue anyway.